# Web App Deployment in Jetty Web Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, opennms

I have developed a Java EE web application in Netbeans and build into a war file. It works fine when deployed in GlassFish application server. However, my aim is to make the this web application work in an OpenNMS application server which contains a build-in Jetty Web server. For this purpose, I extracted the content of the .war file and put it under the directory of the Jetty web server (i.e. /opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/) and attempted to run the default.jsp page that should simply show some information from a database. Then, I get an HTTP 404 Not Found error on the browser. This implies Jetty does not recognize my application at all. I tried restarting the entire openNMS but still getting the same 404 message.

My question here is how I can deploy my web application as a war file into Jetty web server. I guess putting the extracted content under jetty-webapps folder should be sufficient. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off opennms would have to be configured to scan for new webapps on a given location, which I don't know if it is or not.  If it is then you should just have to drop the war file into whatever directory it is configured to scan for new webapps in.

You'll also have to make sure it is configured to start with jsp support enabled.

To really answer the question, *yes* jetty can deploy your webapp but your not really dealing with stock jetty here I don't think, your dealing with opennms configuration and how it uses jetty.  It could just be using a stock jetty distribution or it might be using it embedded in some way.  I retagged this opennms as well for you, maybe you'll pick up someone that knows how opennms works because this isn't strictly a 'jetty' issue or question.

Comment: This link helped me a lot. At least I know my JSP code is running. However, now I get the following in the browser:

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /PMCounters/default.jsp. Reason:

    javax/faces/model/SelectItem

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/SelectItem
 at com.ericsson.dae.pm.dao.VirtualDaeConfigTableDAO.<init>(VirtualDaeConfigTableDAO.java:41)
 at org.apache.jsp.default_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.default_jsp:162)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste the link. Here it is: 

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JSF+Reference+Implementation